# Calling param as string but instead is counting len

Tags: python, sql-server

I'm passing a param to a SQL file to execute, and it's returning the error like python is counting the amount of characters of the string. My python code looks like this:

```py
def check_fat(num_pedido):

    with open("sql_queries/check_fat.sql", "r") as f:
        sql_query_check_fat = f.read()

    df_check_fat = pd.read_sql(sql_query_check_fat, conn, params=(num_pedido))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    num_pedido = '20210601'
    
    check_fat(num_pedido)
```

My SQL file:

```sql
DECLARE @num_pedido CHAR(8);
SELECT @num_pedido = ?;

SELECT *  
FROM table
WHERE column = @num_pedido
```

Error: **('The SQL contains 1 parameter markers, but 8 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')** which it's exactly the size of `num_pedido = '20210601'`

I'm using ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server.

Comment: `params` should probably be a tuple, ie `..., params=(num_pedido,))` (note the trailing comma)

Comment: oh my... you're right, I was changing the whole code for the past hour